# Hexadecimal enumeration OR integer (ASCII) enumeration to fill a byte array with?

Tags: c, arrays, hex, byte, unsigned-char

I need to fill a byte array in c language by the possible enumerations.

Here it is how I declare my byte array:

```
unsigned char byteArray[6];
```

And now I hesitate if my enumrations should look like `MyEnum1` or `MyEnum2`:

```
enum MyEnum1 { A1 = 0, B1 = 1, C1 = 2};
enum MyEnum2 { A2 = 0x00, B2 = 0x01, C2 = 0x02};
```

The purpose is something like this:

```
byteArray[0]=A1;
byteArray[1]=B1;
byteArray[2]=C1;
byteArray[3]=A2;
byteArray[4]=B2;
byteArray[5]=C2;
```

So, is there any recommandations about if my enumerations should contain hexadecimal or integers or another type of data??

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case no matter how you will organize your `enum`. You can do it in both ways and the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. Your two enumerations:

```
enum MyEnum1 { A1 = 0, B1 = 1, C1 = 2};
enum MyEnum2 { A2 = 0x00, B2 = 0x01, C2 = 0x02};
```

are strictly equivalent, just as `int i = 0x5` is strictly quivalent to `int i = 5`. It's up to you if you want to use decimal or hexadecimal representations of your constants.

And BTW instead of:

```
unsigned char byteArray[6];
```

you should probably have:

```
enum MyEnum1 byteArray[6];
```